# Why doesn't shapes drawn on canvas appear on a single column kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to have an infinite amount of shapes drawn on a canvas so I decided to use a scrollview to do this. However, when I add a scroll view none of the shapes appear on the canvas.

py:

```
# draws the shape
def draw_streak(self, obj):
    name = obj.id

    with open("streak.json", "r") as file:
        read = json.load(file)

    for key in read.keys():
        if key == name:
            with open("streak.json", "r+") as f:
                data = json.load(f)

            get_score = data.get(key, {}).get('score')

            can = self.root.get_screen("three")
            new_pos = can.pos
            for x in range(-1, get_score): # had to use -1 to get correct amount of shapes
                with can.ids.my_box.canvas:
                    Color(0, 1, 0, .75, mode='rgba')
                    rect = Rectangle(pos=new_pos, size=(30,30))
                new_pos[0] += rect.size[1]
                new_pos[0] += rect.size[0]
```

kv:

```
<ScreenThree>
    id: screen_three
    name: "three"
    on_leave: my_box.canvas.clear()
    on_leave: selected_streak.canvas.clear()
    on_leave: del_space.canvas.clear()

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 2
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            rows: 1
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: "left"
                anchor_y: "top"
                Button:
                    text: "Back"
                    size: 50, 25
                    size_hint: None, None
                    font_size: 18
                    on_release: app.root.current = "two"
            AnchorLayout:
                id: selected_streak
                anchor_x: "center"
                anchor_y: "top"
            AnchorLayout:
                id: del_space
                anchor_x: "right"
                anchor_y: "top"
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                id: my_box
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_force_default: True
                row_default_height: 50
```

Also, would changing the x size hint make it so that shapes that don't fit will be moved down the screen?

***EDIT***

Draw streak is called when pressing a button at a certain time.

```
...
                elif delay > time.time() > self.honey:  # on time (green)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [0, 1, 0, .95]
                    child.unbind(on_press=self.early_click)
                    child.bind(on_press=self.add_score)
                    child.bind(on_press=self.display_streak)
                    child.bind(on_press=self.draw_streak)
                    child.unbind(on_press=self.late_click)
```

The key of a json value `score` has the same name as the buttons id.

***EDIT***

Screenshots

[image: PageTwo]

[image: PageThree]

Comment: `draw_streak()` method is invoked from a button in which screen?

Comment: ScreenTwo @ikolim

Comment: I don't think the `ScrollView` will recognize that you are trying to scroll the `Canvas`. I believe you will need to add a widget to your `GridLayout` for each new shape, and draw the shape in that widgets `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 3

> is there a way for my rectangles to move down once they exit the
>   screen, or once they reach a certain number?

### Solution

Draw the rectangles from left to right, and top to bottom (lr-tb) orientation.

#### Snippets

```
    root = App.get_running_app().root
    can = root.get_screen('three')
    new_pos = can.pos
    new_pos[1] = root.height - 60    # below the Back button

    for x in range(-1, get_score): # had to use -1 to get correct amount of shapes
        with can.canvas:
            Color(0, 1, 0, .75, mode='rgba')
            rect = Rectangle(pos=new_pos, size=(30,30))

        new_pos[0] += rect.size[0] * 2    # x co-ordinate
        if new_pos[0] >= (root.width - rect.size[0]):
            new_pos[0] = 0    # x co-ordinate
            new_pos[1] -= rect.size[0] * 2    # y co-ordinate
```

#### Output - Demo

[image: Demot]

## Question 2

> wanted the shape to be drawn on page three, not the button.

### Solution

- Replace `with can.ids.my_box.canvas:` with `with can.canvas:`

#### Snippets

```
        can = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('three')
        new_pos = can.pos
        for x in range(-1, get_score): # had to use -1 to get correct amount of shapes
            with can.canvas:
                Color(0, 1, 0, .75, mode='rgba')
                rect = Rectangle(pos=new_pos, size=(30,30))
            new_pos[0] += rect.size[1]
            new_pos[0] += rect.size[0]
```

### Output

[image: Result - draw shapes on ScreenThree]

## Draw shapes on button in ScrollView

- Implement a method `get_cell()` to get an instance of the button inside `my_box`

### Snippets

```
    def get_cell(self, key):
        obj = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('three')

        for row in reversed(obj.ids.my_box.children):
            if row.children:    # children is not empty
                for child in reversed(row.children):
                    if isinstance(child, Button):
                        if child.id == key:
                            return child
            elif isinstance(row, Button):
                if row.id == key:
                    return row
        return None

    def draw_streak(self, obj):
       ... 
            button = self.get_cell(key)    # get button instance
            if button:    # Not None
                new_pos = button.pos    # get button's position

                for x in range(-1, get_score):
                    with button.canvas:
                        Color(0, 1, 0, .75, mode='rgba')
                        rect = Rectangle(pos=new_pos, size=(30,30))
                    new_pos[1] += rect.size[1]    # y co-ordinate
                    new_pos[0] += rect.size[0]    # x co-ordinate
```

### Output

[image: Demo]

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'` also `third` in `obj = ` should be `three`

Comment: After invoking `self.get_cell(key)`, check that it is not `None` before drawing the rectangle(s). Please refer to updated post.

Comment: When I impliment this code, I still have no shapes drawn on my canvas. I decided to check to see if `button is not None` by printing hello if this was the case. When I tried this the console printed `WARNING] Deprecated property "<StringProperty name=id>" of object "<__main__.StreakButton object at 0x0000025E3A666180>" has been set, it will be removed in a future version`. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the problem.

Comment: The warning is not causing the problem. How many button is in a row? Is the rectangle(s) to be drawn on the button within the first page of the `ScrollView`?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn’t clear, I wanted the shape to be drawn on page three, not the button. I just use the button to change the screen and add the shapes on to the screen.

Comment: Please share screen shots of page two and three so that we are on the same page.

Comment: I've added screenshots to my question.

Comment: Replace `with can.ids.my_box.canvas`: with `with can.canvas:`. Please refer to updated post for details.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way for my rectangles to move down once they exit the screen, or once they reach a certain number?

Comment: If you start from bottom, it won't move down because there is no room / space. Draw the rectangles from left to right, and top to bottom (lr-tb) orientation. Please refer to updated post for details.